# Video sharing in Windows phone( Lumia 720)

Tags: video

I am using Nokia lumia 720 which is an awesome phone but lacks a very basic requirement that is sharing Video through bluetooth. Can anyone tell me when it will be developed and released? Is Microsoft looking after this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It's nearly impossible to guess what features will appear in future version of Windows Phone unless the information is leaked or Microsoft explicitly say a feature is coming (eg. Rotation Lock on GDR3/Update 3).

As a Windows Phone user, all you can is search through the [Feature Suggestion site (UserVoice)](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions) and see if the feature idea has already been submitted.

In the case of sharing videos via Bluetooth, it looks like the idea has been submitted [a couple](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4501633-share-videos-via-bluetooth-and-third-party-apps) [of times](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/216486-windows-phone-app-studio/suggestions/4283104-share-videos-via-bluetooth) but doesn't have many votes. Maybe adding your votes will help?

Answer (score 0):

Well i have sorted out the method of sharing video.
make sure the vidoes are saved in phone memory in the camera roll folder.
Open the camera roll folder and tap the vidoe then a sharing option will appear. Select bluethooth option & share.